# How to preserve image quality while creating youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I was trying to make a youtube channel page, and found that they have changed their channel page structure. Now they have something called "One Channel" and asking to upload an image of 2120 X 1192 pixels.

Good so far. The problem is, when I upload an image, the uploaded image shows a much lesser quality.

Any idea on how to overcome this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your final image (2120X1192) in PNG file format, that should solve the problem.
The same thing significantly improves quality of both channel art and avatar.